# iOS socket inputstream blocking UI, but not scheduled on main thread

Tags: ios, swift, inputstream, grand-central-dispatch

When my app receives data over a network input stream, the corresponding streamDelegate is called on the main thread. When receiving a lot of data, the UI blocks notable.
I tried to fire all corresponding functions from a

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .whatever).sync()
```

but although the

```
inputStream.schedule(in: .current,forMode: .commonModes)
```

is called in that queue, the streamDelegate is still called on Main?!

From what I read and understand until now is that .sync wouldn't help me anyway, because it would still block the UI as it would wait to finish before it gives the control back to the UI. So I tried the same with .async. When all that stream-stuff is working on an async thread, the outputStream is working fine, but the inputStreams' streamDelegate doesn't fire. I don't receive a response.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class AppDelegate {
  let mSocketClass = SocketClass()
  func application(_:){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async(){
      mSocketClass.setupNetworkCommunication()
      mSocketClass.sendStuff()
    }
  } 
}
```

.

```
class SocketClass:NSObject {
  var mInputStream: InputStream!
  var mOutputStream: OutputStream!

  func setupNetworkCommunication(){
    var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, "example.com" as CFString, 1234, &readStream, &writeStream)
    mInputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
    mOutputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()
    mInputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .commonModes) //happens on thread other than Main
    mOutputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .commonModes)
    mInputStream.open()
    mOutputStream.open()
    mInputStream.delegate = self
  }

  func sendStuff(){
    if mOutputStream.hasSpaceAvailable {
      mOutputStream.write(...)
    }
  }
}

extension SocketClass:StreamDelegate{
  func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    switch eventCode {
      case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
        (aStream as! InputStream).read(...) //happens on Main
    }
  }
}
```

BTW: I don't like the solution of using a Framework. It seems to me that the solution is to change a single row I just don't understand.

thx!

Comment: I found something relavent in the following answer. [Please check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37430072/5332817)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but sadly this doesnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is almost fine, but you need to start a run loop on that thread.

So it should look like:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async(){
    self.mSocketClass.setupNetworkCommunication()
    RunLoop.current.run()
}
```

Please note:

- `RunLoop.current.run()` never returns. Should be the last line in your setup.
- Data is received then on a background thread. If you want to update your user interface after receiving data, you must use `DispatchQueue.main.async() { /* UI updates */ }`

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Wow! What an enlightening answer. Suddenly everything is so smooth ;). Sadly sometimes the inputStream-Delegate still doesn't fire although the OutputStream.write was successful. In these cases, run() has returned immediately. But I only call run() when inputStream.status is .open (otherwise I do retry-logic). So under which circumstances would run() return at all (in the context of streams)? Many thanks anyway!!!

Comment: Nevermind, found the cause. The retry logic used more queues and maybe run() was called on another queue then inputstream.schedule().